# Change default login pages from admin panel in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have admin panel which has various function. Also there are two login forms on front end of the site:

1. http://example.com/login
2. http://example.com/login2

The default login form is `http://example.com/login` there is button on it which user can click if he/she want to use second login form.

Those are routes for them

```
Route::get ('/users/login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@login', 'before' => 'guest']);
Route::get ('/users/no_login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@no_login', 'before' => 'guest']);
```

What are the options to have switcher in my admin panel from where I can switch the default page for login page e.g. switch between `login` and `login2`. 
If I put them in database what I need to change in routes to get current active form or there is another way?

edit

```
public function login() {       
    $login = Preferences::all();

    if ($login->preferences_login == 0){
        return View::make('users.login');
    }
    return View::make('users.no_login');           
}
```

error is

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$preferences_login

Comment: You don't have to have any switcher just make a link to that route and view and that's it...please provide more information.

Comment: @lewis4u I have view and route. Routes are in my question. I want to be able to change the default login page from admin panel. Not user to click on link on one form to change to other. And I want to be able to control this from my backend

Comment: Yes, when user click on Login button on site will open one of those: `login` or `login2`. Which one will be opened is depends of which one is set as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can solve this in various ways.

Like you said in Admin panel make some link to switch the value in DB and you need to have only one Route in routes/web.php

```
Route::get ('/users/login', ['uses' => 'UsersController@login', 'before' => 'guest']);
```

and then in that controller function login() you can check

```
if ($db_value == 1){
    return view('login');
} else {
    return view('no_login');
}
```

and return the corresponding view

Or you could just make some variable in .env file

```
APP_FLAVOUR=your_flavour
```

And check it also in controller

```
if (env('APP_FLAVOUR') == your_flavour){
    return view('login');
} else {
    return view('no_login');
}
```

But this one is more like a fix value if you won't change it often.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try and will post the result.

Comment: A question about the .env file. What is the usage here? If I set login to env I will need again to put the value in database for the another login view?

Comment: In .env is more if you don't want to change it often, it's more like a fix value...if you need it to have it dynamic then the idea with DB is better

Comment: Okay. Sorry for delay. Will try in a min.

Comment: I've updated my question with how I try and what error I've got. Why is this error?

Comment: It's because Preferences:all() returns a collection... there should be only one value in DB table which you should check.... one column with boolean 0 or 1

Comment: Oh, there are other columns in preferences. Do I need to put IF condition in foreach then to extract only `preferences_login` oclumn or I can access it directly without foreach

Comment: No you don't have to...just tell me how is it named, that value in your preferences which decides what login you will use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140161/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-vls).

Comment: Seems like this made the trick: `$login = DB::table('preferences')->pluck('preferences_login');`